# UITableView - Displaying Delete Button Manually

Tags: ios

When you swipe right, you get the delete button. Pretty.
I'd like to get the identical functionality when swiping left. possible?

I have the swipe backwards implemented and it's catching the action, its just getting it to display the delete button.

Thanks Much
Greg

Comment: You'll need to subclass `UITableViewCell`, add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to it's view and handle the swipe when recognised.

Comment: Should edit the post. I have everything except the displaying of the button.

Comment: Add the button as a subview?..

Comment: Was trying to avoid that route, but agreed, might be only option.

Comment: It's the only option... you will at some point, need to add the button as a subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem I sort of created for myself as, by default, swipe left will bring up the delete button.
Where I got into trouble was that my goal was to swipe right to increment a number and swipe left to decrement, but if was at 1, I wanted to offer the option to remove the cell.
The solution being attaching UISwipeGestureRecognizer (left) only when the count is > 1.

Thanks for everyone's comments.